# ¿Es posible ejecutar un string binario en Bash?

Tags: string, bash, binario

Quiero ejecutar un string binario en *Bash*, es decir, un string que contiene bytes.

De esta manera cargo los bytes del binario en el string:

```
ejecutable=$(cat /bin/cat)
```

Aunque tiene la siguiente advertencia:

> bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

El contenido del string `$ejecutable` sería el siguiente:

> ELF>�.@@``` �@8 @@@@@@hh��@�@@@00 @ @I>I>``@ ```"0�0�@0�@0�����@��@����@�@ P�tdrr@r@�Q�tdR�td0�0�@0�@��/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNU%=; :!<2,(56.09+-743)

Sería algo como lo siguiente, se evaluaría el string y luego se le pasan parámetros:

```
eval $ejecutable parámetros"
```

¿Es posible ejecutar el string en forma de binario en *Bash*?

Comment: Ese `string binario` como tu lo llamas es un ejecutable en formato ELF para sistemas Linux de 64bits. Dudo mucho que Bash lo pueda ejecutar como tu pretendes, pero siempre lo puedes guardar en un archivo temporal y ejecutarlo desde ahí.

Comment: @Trauma Sí, es que yo quería que el archivo esté en la RAM, ahora se me ocurrió montar una carpeta RAMFS y poner todo ahí... Por fuera de esta pregunta, mi idea general es que funcione como demonio, y desde otras terminales envíe señales al programa, esa parte sí que sé hacerla mediante esperas interminables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desafortunadamente no es posible hacerlo, no se puede desde el string porque si se intenta ejecutarlo desde el intérprete:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 <(cat /bin/cat)
```

Entonces, sale un error:

> /dev/fd/63: error while loading shared libraries: /dev/fd/63: failed to map segment from shared object

Pero si se quiere ejecutar un binario desde la memoria *RAM*, se puede montar una carpeta del tipo `ramfs`:

```
mkdir ./ram
cd ./ram
mount none -t ramfs ./
cp /bin/cat ./
./cat ./cat
```